# Register GitHub OAuth application programmatically

Tags: jenkins, github, oauth

I am trying to write some automation that sets up a Jenkins instance and configures it with the GitHub OAuth Plugin. For this to work, I would need to programmatically register an OAuth Application on GitHub and then pass the generated Client ID and Client Secret to Jenkins. Is this possible?